# Existence and uniqueness of differential equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $f =f(y)$ differential on $\mathbb{R}$, given the initial value $y(x_0) =y_0$ prove that there is a solution to $y' = f(y)$ and its unique ?

I try to solve it with no luck, i am stuck in the very beginning.

Comment: Start with separating the variables.

Comment: @Artem but that works assuming that $f(y) \not =0$ , or am i wrong ?

Comment: Since $f\in C^1$ it'll work for any $y$, you only need to carefully deal with possible improper integrals.